# How to split cells within Bootstrap table which have been already splited

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, html-table

I have a bootstrap table which has multiple rows. I would like to split the cells into different section, I am able to split the row Split-1 but I am confused how to split the Split-1 into Split-2. I am trying to achieve Split-2 using rowspan but for some reason its getting messed up. Can someone please help me.
[image]

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #a854a8;text-align: center;"> MAIN FIELD </td>
            <td > TIME-1 </td>
            <td>
                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.time" id="time" placeholder="Time 2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: #eedded;width: 10%;"> TIME-2 </td>
            <td>
                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" ng-model="formdata.time2" id="time2" placeholder="Time2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close... snippet below should help:

```css
th {
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>column 1</th>
    <th>column 2</th>
    <th>column 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" style="background-color: #a854a8;text-align: center;">Main field</td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #eedded;width: 10%;">Time1 split 1</td>
    <td>split-2 result</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>split-2 result</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #eedded;width: 10%;">Time2 split 1</td>
    <td>split-2 result</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>split-2 result</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```